# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 alongside windows10, the SSD is not recognized

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, raid, ahci

I have DELL Precision, with 512GB SSD. I did shrink the only Drive C,  and made 125 GB of unallocated space to install Ubuntu on it.

restarting the system choosing boot, install Ubuntu, the installation process does not recognize any hard disk except the Flash memory that contains ubuntu bootable.

the information from Windows 10 side:

```
Dell Precision 3520
windows 10 pro
Intel Core i7-7820HQ
BIOS mode UEFI
from the device manager;
Storage Controllers:
        Intel chipset SATA/PCIe RST premium controller
        microsoft spaces storage controller
        microsoft VHD loopback controller
Disk 0: (Basic)
       SSDPEKK NVMe INTEL 512GB       
       Partition Style GPT
Rapid Storage Technology:
       Controller 1, Port 0
       Port Location Internal
       Type PCIe solid-state drive
       System Disk: yes
       Controller Type: NVMe
BIOS options on power up: 
       System Configuration/SATA Operation = RAID on (Intel RST)
```

I've read that the Ubuntu kernel is compatible with RST and should recognize the SSD, Also the Disk 0 is shown as basic which I think means hardware RAID. 
What should do in this case to have a dual boot installation of Ubuntu

Comment: You may also need UEFI & SSD firmware updates. Dell Precision 5820 with PCI NVME SSD UEFI update & SSD firmware update
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2402254

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to reinstall Windows...

Some folks have found the 2nd choice that I provide easier to do...

## Make sure to have a backup of your important Windows files!

You've got a single SSD set up in RAID mode, and the Ubuntu installer won't recognize your SSD until you switch your disk setting in the BIOS from RAID to AHCI.

Making that switch comes with some problems though, as Windows will no longer boot.

**Choice #1:** Looking at this article https://samnicholls.net/2016/01/14/how-to-switch-sata-raid-to-ahci-windows-10-xps-13/ will show you how to make the change without having to reinstall Windows.

- Boot to Windows with your current SATA controller configuration
- Open Device Manager
- Expand Storage Controllers and identify the Intel SATA RAID Controller
- View properties of the identified controller
- On the Driver tab, click the Update driver… button
- Browse my computer…, Let me pick…
- Uncheck Show compatible hardware
- Select Microsoft as manufacturer
- Select Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller as model
- Accept that Windows cannot confirm that this driver is compatible
- Save changes, reboot to BIOS and change RAID SATA Controller to AHCI
- Save changes and reboot normally, hopefully to Windows

Now you should be able to install Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration.

**Choice #2:** See http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/

- Right-click the Windows Start Menu. Choose Command Prompt (Admin).
- If you don’t see Command Prompt listed, it’s because you have already been updated to a later version of Windows.  If so, use this method instead to get to the Command Prompt:
- Click the Start Button and type cmd
- Right-click the result and select Run as administrator
- Type this command and press ENTER: bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal
- If this command does not work for you, try bcdedit /set safeboot minimal
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup (the key to press varies between systems).
- Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID (again, the language varies).
- Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose Command Prompt (Admin).
- Type this command and press ENTER: bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot
- If you had to try the alternate command above, you will likely need to do so here also: bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot
- Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.

Comment: I am not that much familiar with the topic, but I dont think it is a SATA connection, instead is PCIe with NVMe protocol, and what is the point to go back to an old technology of AHCI ?

Comment: The point is to make it work with Ubuntu (and Windows). Where did you read that Ubuntu was compatible with RST? My answer has fixed many such problems for other users.

Comment: Ok, it was my bad, Intel enhanced MD RAID to support RST metadata and OROM and it is validated and supported by Intel for `server platforms`.

Comment: thanks, but as it is a long process to backup (it is a work laptop and dont want any mess :D) so for sure I will mark it as answer later if succeeded