# install ubuntu 18.04 in dell inspiron 3480

Tags: boot, system-installation, dell

I recently buy a dell inspiron 3480, in which ubuntu 18.04 lts was installed by default. Then I installed windows 10 “sucesfully”. But after a while, I had an issue with 100% disck usage by windows process, So I decided to go back to ubuntu. However, I am having trouble with the installation of ubuntu, founding this info https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201810-26530, in which you can find that “Standard images of Ubuntu may not work at all on the system or may not work well”.

I installed ubuntu normally from usb, but now, the computer does not boot at all.

My final objective is to make a dual boot in this laptop. Any advices on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Update: in this link I store some pictures of the bios setup of my laptop:
https://github.com/nmolanog/dell_3480_bios

The error message is : "No boot device found".

I am pretty confused since the boot options are not as simple as I used to. There are several options for this. I hope some one expert could check the settings and help me out a bit to get the appropriate settings to run ubuntu.

Comment: Did you install Windows in UEFI boot mode? Have you updated UEFI from Dell? What video do you have? Is Ubuntu now in UEFI boot mode? Dell does often have its own drivers, but releases them & they are included in later versions of Ubuntu. If installed & not booting: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Updated please check. Thanks

Comment: I would change  to UEFI Secure Boot off. Some older Dell seemed to need to have Legacy on, but boot in UEFI mode to have all the drivers. You should not have to use key manager and then only from Ubuntu installer in UEFI Secure boot mode and if you have proprietary driver which you have to assign your own key. You show not Windows nor ubuntu uefi boot entry? Post Boor-Repair  Summary Report when Ubuntu live installer in UEFI boot mode. Dell 3520 Turn off RAID & change to AHCI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096492/installing-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-windows10-the-ssd-is-not-recognized

Answer (score 0):

What is the message you receive when your computer doesn't boot?  Do you know if you installed GRUB as your bootloader, or are you letting Windows handle it.  GRUB will automatically configure a dual boot Ubuntu and Windows configuration. If your problem is that GRUB isn't working, you can try rebuilding it by dropping into a root terminal and using the `update-grub` command.

You can find out how to gain access to root terminal on an installation that doesn't boot here.

[How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Updated. Please take a look at bios images. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to switch from UEFI to legacy in BIOS and try to do a clean install.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please clarify more as to why/how to do this? One sentence although it may help to fix the user's problem short term is not very helpful long-term. (Teach a man to fish...)

Comment: updated showing bios setup. I will apreciate if you can check this.

Comment: Installing from legacy BIOS created problems for me since u should have a EFI boot partition in dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

How are you? I discovery a way to format without this errors.

This error it's due the pendrive bootable not support the UEFI boot.

I did a new bootable pendrive, now supporting the UEFI boot and work's correctly finally.

I used [Yumi multiboot UEFI mode](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), Download the option Yumi UEFI Download, make new pendrive bootable and the next steps are the same.

Also, a friend used the **Startup Disk** to generate a bootable pendrive in linux, this worked fine too.