# Ubuntu dualboot install not recognizing unallocated space

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, windows-10

I followed various articles to install ubuntu 18.04 in parallel to my windows 10 OS.

I have allocated 150 gigs of free space and get to the point where I can boot from my Usb which contains the ISO image.

However when I resume to install ubuntu it keeps telling me that there is not enough space and it appears that it is only taking into account the space on the USB stick and not what have allocated shrinking the Volume of my C drive.

I am at a loss here and any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Have you updated UEFI and if SSD, the SSD firmware? Is drive set for AHCI, not RAID nor Intel RST? Is Windows 10 in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? If vendor install, it must be UEFI. But if upgrade from Windows 7, probably BIOS/MBR with a 4 primary partition limit.

Comment: The questions i can answer for sure is that it is UEFI and vendor install.

Comment: `sudo parted --list` please.

Comment: @nobody, i ran the command and it just gives me information about the usb drive, sorry i have no means of pasting the exact output here.  Please let me know if that helps in anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Ubuntu 18.04 alongside windows10, the SSD is not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096492/installing-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-windows10-the-ssd-is-not-recognized)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by going into BIOS and changing my SATA options from RAID to AHCI and afterwards I had to rename some file in my USB installer to get the boot going again. Thanks all for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

when you install, there should be an option called 'something else'. There you can select which partition and disk you want the installation to be on. it should be across the bottom under the diagram of your currently selected disk.

Comment: I can't even get to the 'something else' option the warning is displayed and I cannot continue.

Comment: is your computer currently in the installation process?

Comment: the option should be right after you select 'normal installation' or 'minimal install', which stage is the warning displayed?

Comment: No , as i say , I select the country and language and it is right after that that the error is thrown.

Comment: You could try loading ubuntu into ram and then install it. When you select 'install ubuntu', press `e` and add the word ‘toram’ right after the word ‘boot=casper’ and before ‘quiet’. Then unplug the USB so it doesn't get picked up.

Comment: Drive not able to be found is either or both SSD firmware not updated or drive not in ACHI mode in UEFI settings.

Comment: @Kenivia, I tried that but when I press e it doesn't stop anything and the installer keeps going, am i missing a step?

Comment: @oldfred, so how do I fix this?

Comment: Are drive(s) set for AHCI, not RAID in UEFI? Is Windows fast start up off? Have you updated UEFI from vendor and SSD firmware? What brand/model system? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: @newbuntu it's when you select between `try ubuntu without installing` and `install ubuntu`, highlight try ubuntu and press e. This way you can make sure everything is running and then unplug and launch the installer by clicking on it on desktop.

Comment: @Kenivia, I get hd0.msdos1 not found when i do that. Any ideas?

Comment: @newbuntu ok, i dont think that is going to work. Select `try ubuntu without installing`, boot up, and try  `gparted` If the disk doesn't show up in gparted(top right corner to select), then you might be in some trouble. And make sure everything oldfred mentioned is taken care of. UEFI, Windows fast startup etc. Also, maybe try putting ubuntu on the stick again(redownload) Corrupted files might cause unexpected errors and show up like this. Make sure you run a checksum on the downloade iso file.

Comment: Guys, I went to the bios and changed my SATA option from RAID to AHCI and that solved the problem for a moment, I had to exit that install since I had actually assigned a Drive letter to my unallocated space and Ubuntu did not allow me to use it for the install.  I went back to windows deleted the drive which put the memory into the "unallocated" . Now when i try to boot from usb to do the install, it is telling me that a bunch of files cannot be found.  I recreated my bootable USB but still the same issue. the error disappears fast and i cannot capture it quickly. any ideas?

Comment: @newbuntu At which stage of the install did the errors occur? or did it just fail to boot?