# How to speed up my new 'supposedly' high powered computer

Tags: image-processing, hardware-acceleration, optimization

Does anyone have some tips for ways I can optimize/improve the speed of my computer? Just bought a new one, intended for neuroimaging analysis, and i installed ubuntu. I know there's some features of this computer I am not accessing properly. I bought one with similar specs to one I used previously, but it's running very slowly, and can't seem to even handle some basic tasks.

Here are the specs:

```
Precision 3630 Tower CTO BASE (210-AOZN )
Precision 3630 Tower with 460W up to 90% efficient PSU (80Plus Gold) with SD card reader v2 (321-BESW )
Intel Xeon CPU label (338-BOME )
Intel Xeon E-2246G, 6 Core, 12MB Cache, 3.6Ghz, 4.8Ghz Turbo w/UHD Graphics 630 (338-BTJZ )
16GB 2x8GB 2666MHz DDR4 ECC Memory (370-AEEM )
Precision 3630, 460W Reg Label DAO (389-CUOR )
M.2 512GB PCIe NVMe Class 40 Solid State Drive, Self-Encrypting Drive , Opal 2.0 (400-AYHK )
3.5 inch 2TB 7200rpm SATA Hard Disk Drive (401-ABPW )
Boot drive or storage volume is greater than 2TB (select when 3TB/4TB HDD is ordered) (411-XXYB 
Dell Precision Tower 3630 Heatsink (80) (412-AAOU )
8x DVD+/-RW 9.5mm Optical Disk Drive (429-ABDW )
C5 M.2 SSD + 3.5 1-3 HD (449-BBMM )
Nvidia Quadro P2200, 5GB, 4 DP (3630) (490-BFOO )
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware? Dell Precision 3520 Turn off RAID & change to AHCI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096492/installing-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-windows10-the-ssd-is-not-recognized
If slow booting: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service

Comment: Thank you I will try that. Is there anything I should/can do to make sure I'm making good use of the Xeon 6 core?

Comment: Not seen many Xeon systems. Most are desktop or laptop CPUs. What is slow? If Boot issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service

Comment: It's not a boot issue, it's more that when I try to run a memory-intensive analysis, it goes slowly, or in some cases stops altogether, saying it's out of memory

Comment: Then keep terminal Windows open with top or htop (you have to install htop which is slightly better) and see what is consuming resources and/or system monitor to pretty much see same info with less detail but whether CPU, network or drives. Your 16GB is a lot for normal use, but if something memory intensive it may need more. You can add more swap into fast NVMe drive, but that still is orders of magnitude slower than RAM.