# Can't boot from UEFI with Ubuntu 20

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 20 on my Dell Precision Tower 3620 and now it won't boot. Here's the sequence of events:

1. I put the Ubuntu installer on a USB stick using Rufus and booted Ubuntu successfully from that, using the "Try Ubuntu" option.
2. I installed Ubuntu on the PC, using the default options to wipe the disk and create new partitions.
3. Ubuntu booted successfully. It prompted me to install updates and reboot, which I allowed.
4. The PC failed to find a boot disk. (It attempted network boot, which is one of the later options in the BIOS boot sequence.)
5. I rebooted and hit F2 for the BIOS setup. I changed the boot options to use UEFI, which listed "ubuntu" under it. I saved the options and rebooted.
6. On rebooting, PC showed the black-and-white Dell logo, with a spinning circle under it, and "ubuntu" at the bottom of the screen. It stayed like that for at least 10 minutes. Power cycling and trying again didn't help.
7. Hitting F2 for the BIOS setup, or F12 for the one-time boot menu no longer has any effect. It goes immediately to the Dell logo/spinning circle/ubuntu screen and stays there.
8. Using the jumper on the motherboard to reset the CMOS got it back to the state where it fails to find a legacy boot disk, and I can use the one-time boot menu to boot Ubuntu. But presumably, it would stop booting again if I selected the UEFI boot as default.

Do I need to do something else to get it to boot Ubuntu from UEFI by default?

Comment: It looks like you may have installed Ubuntu in the legacy mode. If that's not what you want, install again. This time make sure the installation USB boots in the UEFI mode. If the USB boots in the legacy you will get a legacy install. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg/1134955#1134955) for how to know if your USB is booting in UEFI or Legacy mode, before you install.

Comment: Rufus seems to make either only UEFI(gpt) or only BIOS(CSM/BIOS) installers. ISO is for both/either normally. So you have to create UEFI version. Then install in UEFI mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi Dell also need UEFI update, SSD firmware update, AHCI for drives and maybe some more settings. Dell Precision 3520 Turn off RAID & change to AHCI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096492/installing-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-windows10-the-ssd-is-not-recognized

Comment: Please clarify your release(s).  Ubuntu uses *yy* releases only for specialist *snap* based releases for IoT appliances/devices or cloud based use (having done so since 2016). Main releases use *yy.mm* such as used by server & desktops releases.