# How to make Ubuntu recognize a drive on a Dell Inspiron 3593 laptop?

Tags: drivers, dell, intel

I'm trying to to install Ubuntu on a Dell Inspiron 3593 laptop which is supposed to be Ubuntu-certified as said [here](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201907-27241).

I have tried Ubuntu 20.04, 20.10 and a 21.04 daily build but neither of them could detect any disk drives. I've seen some clues on the Internet suggesting 10th gen Intel CPU or the according chipset is to blame.

Any ideas on how to fix this gracefully?

Comment: You might want to [follow the instructions](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000131655/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc) set out by Dell on how to do this. You will likely need to make some changes in the BIOS before you can install the operating system.

Comment: Dell issues common across similar models: Dell  Inspiron 3670 UEFI update & AHCI worked
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2412152
Dell Inspiron 3593 Minor issues with fixes
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2448590 Dell Precision 3520 Turn off RAID & change to AHCI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096492/installing-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-windows10-the-ssd-is-not-recognized