# Windows 10 installs on my system but ubuntu gets an error 5

Tags: 20.04, windows-10

I have an old dell inspiron 15 3567 laptop. It came with windows 10 home. I upgraded it to win10 pro and it installed smoothly. Today I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04.3 but it says error 5. I again tried win10 from a usb stick and there is no problem. Why is this happening?

Comment: Without seeing the *exact* error messages you're seeing, the error codes aren't going to be helpful.  Can you show us the exact error message and any logs from the installer that it shows prior to the error?

Comment: Dell Inspiron 3567 Review i3 7100u (Works well)
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2364642 Similar: Dell Precision 3520 Turn off RAID & change to AHCI
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096492/installing-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-windows10-the-ssd-is-not-recognized