# Inspiron 15 3525 w/new Ubuntu install won't turn on after closing lid

Tags: dell, power-management, laptop, lid

A dear friend, disabled Vietnam vet, had to replace his old computer, and bought a Dell Inspiron 15 (3525) and asked me to put Ubuntu on it. After a somewhat fraught install process (BIOS in this model is new and different from what I'm familiar with). Finally got the USB drive to boot, got the Ubuntu installed (wiped the drive), and got a bunch of work done...until I closed the lid to get a coffee. I came back to a dead machine. It simply will not turn on, no matter if on the adapter, or battery, or whatever. I'm seeing "remove the battery and drain the flea power" which I'm willing to do, but WTF caused this in the first place? I've been using/installing Ubuntu for years and never ran into this. Help, please.

Comment: The laptop model is listed. It's 20.04 desktop. Anything else?

Comment: Dell often needs UEFI(BIOS) update. Did you install in UEFI mode or old BIOS/CSM mode.  CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode.  Dell Precision 3520 Turn off RAID & change to AHCI Older model, with older Ubuntu worked.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096492/installing-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-windows10-the-ssd-is-not-recognized

Comment: There is no RAID on this machine; AHCI is on. Brand new Inspiron 15-3525. The OS, apps, etc. were loaded and running until I closed the lid. I think some folks are missing my point...I cannot even try to update BIOS unless the machine will just turn on. That's the immediate problem. I guess I have to "flea-drain" it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be something to do with the BIOS, obviously, but I fixed it by removing the cover, disconnecting the integrated battery and line power, and hitting the power button to ground the circuits and drain the "flea" power. Put it back together and working OK. My point here is that I can now close the lid without a problem...but I suggest if one is installing on one of these lower-end Dells that they be VERY careful to, immediately after installing, change the Ubuntu settings to NOT allow suspend, etc. BEFORE even closing the lid for the first time. Seems that is what triggered it.